# Trying to understand bloc code but getting (runZoned is deprecated, and Zone mismatch)

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am teaching myself bloc but there is this segment of code which is deprecated:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  BlocOverrides.runZoned(
        () async {
      DioHelper.init();
      await CacheHelper.init();
      final locale =
          CacheHelper.getDataFromSharedPreference(key: 'language') ?? "ar";
      delegate = await LocalizationDelegate.create(
        fallbackLocale: locale,
        supportedLocales: ['ar', 'en'],
      );
      await delegate.changeLocale(Locale(locale));
      runApp(MyApp(
        appRouter: AppRouter(),
      ));
    },
    blocObserver: MyBlocObserver(),
  );
}
```

which I think resulted in Zone mismatch exception .

I tried to learn how to fix it but I didn't know where to put the rest of the code which includes (Initializations & localization).

It would be great if someone helped teaching me the problem, and how to fix it because I don't understand this part really well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to restructure the code like that:

```
//Initialisations
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationUtil.init();
  DioHelper.init();
  await CacheHelper.init();

  //Bloc Observer
  Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();

  //Locals
  final locale =
      CacheHelper.getDataFromSharedPreference(key: 'language') ?? "en";
  delegate = await LocalizationDelegate.create(
    fallbackLocale: locale,
    supportedLocales: ['ar', 'en'],
  );
  await delegate.changeLocale(Locale(locale));

  //runApp, with appRouter
  runApp(MyApp(
    appRouter: AppRouter(),
  ));
```

The whole point is to just remove `runZoned()`, and simply put the rest of the code outside of it, and then you can separately call `Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();`